MySQL pivot dates to column headings without knowing/defining column headings
I'm pivoting dates to column headings but I don't want to have to manually define each date in my query. I want the query to be futureproof. How can I achieve this? Dates are weekly (Wednesdays).
Structure & Data
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `week` date NOT NULL,
  `sales` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `name`, `week`, `sales`) VALUES
(1, 'Aiza Sharp', '2023-11-29', 40),
(2, 'Lorna Duran', '2023-11-29', 31),
(3, 'Harris Mccall', '2023-11-29', 49),
(4, 'Allen Gibbons', '2023-11-29', 18),
(5, 'Melisa Porter', '2023-11-29', 23),
(6, 'Joe Underwood', '2023-11-29', 27),
(7, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2023-11-29', 2),
(8, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2023-11-29', 0),
(9, 'Jorge Olsen', '2023-11-29', 43),
(10, 'Luke Brandt', '2023-11-29', 42),
(11, 'Aiza Sharp', '2023-12-13', 36),
(12, 'Lorna Duran', '2023-12-13', 12),
(13, 'Harris Mccall', '2023-12-13', 8),
(14, 'Allen Gibbons', '2023-12-13', 25),
(15, 'Melisa Porter', '2023-12-13', 45),
(16, 'Joe Underwood', '2023-12-13', 39),
(17, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2023-12-13', 40),
(18, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2023-12-13', 0),
(19, 'Jorge Olsen', '2023-12-13', 20),
(20, 'Luke Brandt', '2023-12-13', 39),
(21, 'Aiza Sharp', '2023-12-20', 8),
(22, 'Lorna Duran', '2023-12-20', 9),
(23, 'Harris Mccall', '2023-12-20', 16),
(24, 'Allen Gibbons', '2023-12-20', 14),
(25, 'Melisa Porter', '2023-12-20', 10),
(26, 'Joe Underwood', '2023-12-20', 29),
(27, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2023-12-20', 22),
(28, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2023-12-20', 0),
(29, 'Jorge Olsen', '2023-12-20', 32),
(30, 'Luke Brandt', '2023-12-20', 26),
(31, 'Aiza Sharp', '2023-12-20', 22),
(32, 'Lorna Duran', '2023-12-20', 47),
(33, 'Harris Mccall', '2023-12-20', 26),
(34, 'Allen Gibbons', '2023-12-20', 24),
(35, 'Melisa Porter', '2023-12-20', 13),
(36, 'Joe Underwood', '2023-12-20', 1),
(37, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2023-12-20', 9),
(38, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2023-12-20', 0),
(39, 'Jorge Olsen', '2023-12-20', 19),
(40, 'Luke Brandt', '2023-12-20', 32),
(41, 'Aiza Sharp', '2023-12-27', 29),
(42, 'Lorna Duran', '2023-12-27', 22),
(43, 'Harris Mccall', '2023-12-27', 11),
(44, 'Allen Gibbons', '2023-12-27', 4),
(45, 'Melisa Porter', '2023-12-27', 34),
(46, 'Joe Underwood', '2023-12-27', 16),
(47, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2023-12-27', 43),
(48, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2023-12-27', 0),
(49, 'Jorge Olsen', '2023-12-27', 4),
(50, 'Luke Brandt', '2023-12-27', 32),
(51, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-01-03', 3),
(52, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-01-03', 5),
(53, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-01-03', 1),
(54, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-01-03', 35),
(55, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-01-03', 46),
(56, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-01-03', 26),
(57, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-01-03', 11),
(58, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-01-03', 0),
(59, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-01-03', 46),
(60, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-01-03', 38),
(61, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-01-10', 50),
(62, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-01-10', 26),
(63, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-01-10', 6),
(64, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-01-10', 29),
(65, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-01-10', 19),
(66, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-01-10', 24),
(67, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-01-10', 32),
(68, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-01-10', 0),
(69, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-01-10', 9),
(70, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-01-10', 31),
(71, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-01-17', 17),
(72, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-01-17', 46),
(73, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-01-17', 38),
(74, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-01-17', 2),
(75, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-01-17', 10),
(76, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-01-17', 4),
(77, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-01-17', 10),
(78, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-01-17', 0),
(79, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-01-17', 14),
(80, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-01-17', 0),
(81, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-01-24', 14),
(82, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-01-24', 16),
(83, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-01-24', 14),
(84, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-01-24', 39),
(85, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-01-24', 23),
(86, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-01-24', 35),
(87, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-01-24', 33),
(88, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-01-24', 0),
(89, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-01-24', 14),
(90, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-01-24', 47),
(91, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-01-31', 2),
(92, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-01-31', 24),
(93, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-01-31', 46),
(94, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-01-31', 47),
(95, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-01-31', 3),
(96, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-01-31', 33),
(97, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-01-31', 24),
(98, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-01-31', 20),
(99, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-01-31', 7),
(100, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-01-31', 48),
(101, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-02-07', 16),
(102, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-02-07', 30),
(103, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-02-07', 19),
(104, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-02-07', 10),
(105, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-02-07', 28),
(106, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-02-07', 11),
(107, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-02-07', 13),
(108, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-02-07', 47),
(109, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-02-07', 5),
(110, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-02-07', 33),
(111, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-02-14', 17),
(112, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-02-14', 12),
(113, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-02-14', 16),
(114, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-02-14', 3),
(115, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-02-14', 33),
(116, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-02-14', 27),
(117, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-02-14', 9),
(118, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-02-14', 7),
(119, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-02-14', 49),
(120, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-02-14', 27),
(121, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-02-21', 8),
(122, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-02-21', 20),
(123, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-02-21', 36),
(124, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-02-21', 35),
(125, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-02-21', 33),
(126, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-02-21', 12),
(127, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-02-21', 36),
(128, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-02-21', 48),
(129, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-02-21', 15),
(130, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-02-21', 15),
(131, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-02-28', 7),
(132, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-02-28', 13),
(133, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-02-28', 35),
(134, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-02-28', 42),
(135, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-02-28', 23),
(136, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-02-28', 37),
(137, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-02-28', 46),
(138, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-02-28', 38),
(139, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-02-28', 38),
(140, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-02-28', 0),
(141, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-03-06', 14),
(142, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-03-06', 40),
(143, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-03-06', 48),
(144, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-03-06', 2),
(145, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-03-06', 29),
(146, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-03-06', 43),
(147, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-03-06', 32),
(148, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-03-06', 21),
(149, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-03-06', 42),
(150, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-03-06', 43),
(151, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-03-13', 8),
(152, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-03-13', 15),
(153, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-03-13', 8),
(154, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-03-13', 6),
(155, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-03-13', 11),
(156, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-03-13', 9),
(157, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-03-13', 18),
(158, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-03-13', 42),
(159, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-03-13', 35),
(160, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-03-13', 47),
(161, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-03-20', 8),
(162, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-03-20', 13),
(163, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-03-20', 35),
(164, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-03-20', 50),
(165, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-03-20', 10),
(166, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-03-20', 25),
(167, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-03-20', 5),
(168, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-03-20', 0),
(169, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-03-20', 17),
(170, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-03-20', 12),
(171, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-03-27', 29),
(172, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-03-27', 44),
(173, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-03-27', 13),
(174, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-03-27', 10),
(175, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-03-27', 50),
(176, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-03-27', 43),
(177, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-03-27', 1),
(178, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-03-27', 41),
(179, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-03-27', 28),
(180, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-03-27', 13),
(181, 'Aiza Sharp', '2024-04-03', 3),
(182, 'Lorna Duran', '2024-04-03', 10),
(183, 'Harris Mccall', '2024-04-03', 6),
(184, 'Allen Gibbons', '2024-04-03', 35),
(185, 'Melisa Porter', '2024-04-03', 23),
(186, 'Joe Underwood', '2024-04-03', 30),
(187, 'Elisabeth Cole', '2024-04-03', 38),
(188, 'Dawid Zimmerman', '2024-04-03', 31),
(189, 'Jorge Olsen', '2024-04-03', 0),
(190, 'Luke Brandt', '2024-04-03', 23);

ALTER TABLE `test_table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `test_table`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=191;
COMMIT;

Query Attempt 1
Manually defines column heading dates.
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2023-11-29' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2023-11-29',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2023-12-06' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2023-12-06',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2023-12-13' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2023-12-13',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2023-12-20' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2023-12-20',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2023-12-27' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2023-12-27',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2023-01-03' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-01-03',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-01-10' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-01-10',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-01-17' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-01-17',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-01-24' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-01-24',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-01-31' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-01-31',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-02-07' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-02-07',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-02-14' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-02-14',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-02-21' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-02-21',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-02-28' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-02-28',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-03-06' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-03-06',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-03-13' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-03-13',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-03-20' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-03-20',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-03-27' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-03-27',
  SUM(CASE WHEN week = '2024-04-03' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '2024-04-03'
FROM test_table
GROUP BY name

Query Attempt 2
I've tried using GROUP_CONCAT following a tutorial:
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when week = ''',
      week,
      ''' then sales end) ',
      week
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM
  test_table;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM test_table 
                   GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

I get the following error using the above query:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '2023-11-29,max(case when week = '2023-12-13' then sales end)
2023-12-13,max(case' at line 1


select @sql - is it valid sql?

@P.Salmon nope, column aliases are nott wrapped into single quotes or backticks.

@P.Salmon I copied that code block from the tutorial and just modified the table name and column headings. I don't understand what (at symbol)sql means and don't know what I should change it to.

@Shadow If you're referring to Query Attempt 1, if I don't wrap the column aliases in single quotes, I get a syntax error.

@ClarusDignus nope, I was referring to the 2nd attempt, where you are not wrapping the column aliases into single quote or backticks.

@Shadow It's not apparent to me where the column aliases are being defined and what needs to be wrapped. I've tried wrapping all column headings in backticks but I'm getting a syntax error, i.e. I've tried wrapping sales, week, and name in backticks.

The 2nd week is the alias. You have to spend a bit more time on understanding what your query is doing, how it assembles the sql query with an sql query. Play around its various parts and check their impact on the generated sql by printing @sql variable's contents.
